# I want to make a power supply using two 18650 batteries in paralell with a TP 4056 module but im not sure how to balance the batteries

Tags: batteries, charging, bms

I am using a TP 4056 module, two 18650 batteries and some sort of BMS to balance the batteries before going to the charging module however I'm not sure whether I need a 2S BMS or a 1S BMS.
Preferably I would want the batteries to be in parallel so how do I go about connecting that to a BMS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parallel two smaller cells, just parallel them and it will look like single larger cell. No BMS needed. Single TP4056 should work fine with it.

Do make sure that the two cells are balanced to same voltage, maybe with a resistor between them, before connecting them in parallel directly.